# WooCommerce. How to add a wrapping div around single pages product descriptions?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am looking for a filter/hook to wrap some extra div around my woocommerce single pages product descriptions included to the tabs.

Right now i have

```
<div class="woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-description" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-title-description" style="display: block;">

<h2>Product Title</h2>

  <p>My Product Description Text</p>

</div>
```

And thats what i would like to achieve instead

```
<div class="woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-description" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-title-description" style="display: block;">

<h2>Product Title</h2>

<div class="nocontent">

  <!-- The area to exclude -->
  <p>My Product Description Text</p>

</div>
</div>
```

So the container `<div class="nocontent">` just around the product description text.

Comment: Have you tried to update woocommerce template files in your child theme?

Comment: you theme create folder woocommerce and add content-single-product.php file add code